# Select element and toggle class to rotate child elements independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I feel like I'm close, but I seem to be at an impasse right now. I'm a js/jquery n00b, so I might be way off and just don't know it.

I've gotten as far as getting the child of the parent div that I click to rotate (toggles the `.rotated` class), then when a *different* parent div is clicked, the `.rotated` class is toggled again and the child div rotates and also removes the `.rotated` class from the child of the parent div that was previously clicked.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to then toggle the `.rotated` class of child div if its parent is clicked *twice in a row*. See the Fiddle at the bottom if this description is confusing.

I know *why* it doesn't work (my `if` statement is `true` when I click a div that's already rotated, and the code inside it is fighting with itself), I just can't quite get my head around how to make it do what I want.

**HTML example** (final product will have multiple divs like this)

```
<div class="one-fourth">
  <div class="collapse-container">Collapser 1
    <div class="plus-logo" id="logo_1">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 144 144" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M2 72.2c0-38.6 31.4-70 70-70 38.6 0 70 31.4 70 70 0 38.7-31.4 70-70 70C33.4 142.2 2 110.9 2 72.2z" fill="#244385" />
        <path d="M59.1 84.5H23.8V58h35.3V22.7h26.5V58h35.3v26.4H85.6v35.3H59.1V84.5z" fill="#FFF" />
        <polygon points="72 7.2 79.1 19.5 64.9 19.5 " fill="#F6D432" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one-fourth {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plus-logo {
  width: 32%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin: 10px auto;

}

.plus-logo svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.rotated {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.collapse-container').click(function() {

  var rotated_logo = $('.collapse-container').find('.rotated').attr('id');  

  if (typeof rotated_logo !== 'undefined') {

    $('#'+rotated_logo).removeClass('rotated');
    $(this).children().toggleClass('rotated');

    } else {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('rotated');
  }

});
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/brentfincham/fzejx81u/16/

Comment: just remove $('#'+rotated_logo).removeClass('rotated'); https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fzejx81u/17/. Since you remove the class, the toggle would not work.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, but then the div that was clicked first doesn't rotate back. I want the first clicked div to toggle back to "start" when any of the other divs are clicked, while also toggling the `.rotated` class when a div is clicked twice in a row. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/tkfg05ta/

```
// store for the last rotated html element
var lastRotated;

// Define the listener on the body element instead of having
//a few listeners for each .collapse-container 
$('body').on('click','.collapse-container', function(e){

  // Get the '.plus-logo' child of the currently clicked element
  var plusLogoNode = $('.plus-logo',this);


  plusLogoNode.toggleClass('rotated');

  // $('selector')[0] - gets the first element from the jquery collection 
  // as pure html node
  // If there is last rotated element and that element is not
  // the currently clicked than remove the class of lastRotated
  (lastRotated && !lastRotated[0].isSameNode(plusLogoNode[0])) && (lastRotated.removeClass('rotated'));

  // Now the last rotated is the current
  lastRotated = plusLogoNode;
});
```

Comment: Close. Made one change and now it's perfect! Changed the end of line 7 from `toggleClass` to `removeClass`. Now to study the code you posted and figure out exactly what it's doing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you made it. Congrats for the fix I edited it in the answer.
If you're not able to figure out something from the code I have added comments.
Please mark my post as the correct answer if the code works as you describe. Thank you.